# What charting library does Azure use for their portal

Tags: azure, charts, azureportal

I like the look and feel of the charts that are in Azure's portal, and I'd like to use them in some of my projects. Does anyone know what JavaScript library they use?

Comment: Not really a SO on-topic question, but I believe the Azure Portal uses custom charting that MS developed just for it.

Comment: With all the existing libraries out there that are pretty dang good already, I'd hope they wouldn't choose build over buy. I'd expect them to put their resources to better use. Why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Well, this is Microsoft we're talking about.

Comment: Yes, it is. As expected they choose the higher route and choose buy over build. See my answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I found that they are using D3.js as their charting library.
https://d3js.org

Comment: hmm.. How did you find this? Do you have a source?

Comment: Why yes, yes I do. 